# How to validate email password without using spring security and authentication in spring boot?

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am new to spring boot as after completing a crud function rest API in spring-boot I'm badly stuck in login rest API for android application where I just want to use email and password in POSTMAPPING. Please anyone could help me here?

**Controller class**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import demo.loginapi.main.model.UserModel;
import demo.loginapi.main.repository.UserRepository;
import demo.loginapi.main.repository.UserService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    
    @GetMapping("/getallusers")
    public List<UserModel> getAllCustomer(){
        List<UserModel> alluserlist = userRepository.findAll();
        return alluserlist;
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login/{email}")
    public List<UserModel> getemailpassword(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email){
        
        List<UserModel> alluseremailpassword = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
        return alluseremailpassword;
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login2/{email}")
    public UserModel getuserbyemail(@PathVariable(value = "email") String email)
      
    {
        UserModel userByEmailForLogin = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        
        return userByEmailForLogin; 
    }
    

    @PostMapping("/loginemailpass/{email}/{password}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> loginUser(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> userMap){
        
        String email = (String) userMap.get("email");
        String password = (String) userMap.get("password");
        
        UserModel userModel = userService.validate(email,password);
        
        return new ResponseEntity<>(generateJWTToken(userModel),HttpStatus.OK);

        
    }

    private  Map<String, String> generateJWTToken(UserModel userModel) {
        
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

** Entity Class **

```
package demo.loginapi.main.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_login")
public class UserModel {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    private Long userId;
    
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    public UserModel() {
        //default constructor
    }
    
    public UserModel(Long userId, String username, String email, String password, String role) {
        //super();
        this.userId = userId;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserModel [userId=" + userId + ", username=" + username + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password
                + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }
    
    
    

}
```

** Repository Class **

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import demo.loginapi.main.model.UserModel;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<UserModel, Long>{

    List<UserModel> findUserByEmail(String email);

    UserModel findByEmail(String email);

    //UserModel validate(String email, String password);

    
    UserModel findByEmailAndPaswword(String email, String password);

    //UserModel findByEmailPassword(String email, String password);

    
    
}
```

** Service Class **

```
import demo.loginapi.main.model.UserModel;

public interface UserService {

    UserModel validate(String email, String password);

}
```

** Service Implementation **

```
package demo.loginapi.main.repository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import demo.loginapi.main.model.UserModel;

@Service
public class UserRepoImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Override
    public UserModel validate(String email, String password) {
        if(email != null) email = email.toLowerCase();
        return userRepository.findByEmailAndPaswword(email, password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly doesn't work, so that we won't have to analyze it line by line?

Comment: In repository class and controller class the way it is defined i.e. "string username, string password", is showing an error as String password not found.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository class , is findByEmailAndPassword is available in jparepository, if not use through @query annotation like @query("select usename from userlogin us where us.username =:email") Something like that in your method.

Also if pre defined method is available please check the spelling, seems incorrect. It has double w in it. findByEmailAndPaswword

Comment: Thank you so much I will definitely go through these solutions.